# Settimeout inside of object method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, settimeout

Given code snippet of code does not stop even though I'm using setTimeout in it.

```
var myObj = {
    myFunc: function () {
        var self = this;
        var timer = setTimeout(function () { 
            console.log('Timeout called'); 
            self.myFunc();
        }, 100);
    }
};
myObj.myFunc();
myObj = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `setTimeout` callback, the given code recursively calling `myFunc` (`self.myFunc()`), that's why it is going forever.

Comment: But, myObj = null ?

Comment: You are already holding a reference to the object with `var self = this;`. When you are setting `myObj = null`, the variable (myObj) is no longer pointing to the object, but the object is still in the memory.